# AngularJS Different URL If

Tags: angularjs

I currently have the following link on my page.

```
<a href="/#!/blog/{{article.id}}" title="Permalink to {{article.title.__cdata}}" itemprop="url">{{article.title.__cdata}}</a>
```

I would like to make a small change, but am not sure of the proper syntax.

If `{{article.url}}` is NOT zero-length, I would like to use that instead of `/#!/blog/{{article.id}}`

If `{{article.url}}` is zero-length, I would like to continue to use `/#!/blog/{{article.id}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a ng-href="{{ article.url || '/#!/blog/' + article.id }}" ...>
```

or you could put this logic in the controller if you find it too complex to be in the view:

```
<a ng-href="{{ getPermalink(article) }}" ...>

$scope.getPermalink = function(article) {
    return article.url || '#!/blog/' + article.id;
}
```